# Changing recordsize on existing ZFS dataset

Tags: zfs

I want to change the `recordsize` property on an existing ZFS dataset.

The man page states:

> Changing the file system's recordsize affects only files created afterward; existing files are unaffected.

So simply changing the `recordsize` property will only have an effect on newly created files. I want existing files to take advantage of the new recordsize as well.

Will a `zfs send`and `zfs receive` of the dataset convert the existing files to to new recordsize or will I have to copy the files off of the dataset manually and then back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to copy the data off and back onto the filesystem if you want to take advantage of the new record size.

I'm not sure what your question is, though.

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify, I wanted to know if copying the dataset  using `zfs send` and `zfs receive` would let me take advantage of the new recordsize for existing files in the dataset.

Comment: The existing files need to go away, otherwise the record size change won't apply.

Comment: `cp -p filename filename.new; mv filename.new filename` won't work, assuming there's enough space?

Answer (score 1):

Late reply, I know, but here are a couple of pointers:

1. `zfs receive` has a `-o recordsize` option which lets you override the value on the receiving end.
2. IMHO syncing ZFS datasets are most easily achieved with syncoid's help (which is part of the [Sanoid](https://github.com/jimsalterjrs/sanoid) suite).  For example, the following reasonably simple command line would replicate the given dataset from existing Zpools `apool` to `bpool` whilst forcing the desired `recordsize` to 64k on the receiving end:

   ```
   syncoid --recursive --recvoptions="o recordsize=64k" apool/DATASET bpool/DATASET
   ```

`syncoid` is a wrapper around `zfs send/receive`, which operates off snapshots that it manages itself; so you can use it while your system is running and also send incrementals.  `--recvoptions` are passed through to `zfs receive`.  This option is only documented in `syncoid`'s manpage, not on the Github page, but it works exactly as expected.

Comment: Are you sure this works? If I understand https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/issues/9347#issuecomment-534173536 correctly then you can not not change the recordsize with `zfs receive`

Comment: @user643011 You're right, I should have qualified that the destination dataset (targetted by `zfs receive`)  should be empty so that the source dataset's `recordsize` is indeed overridden.  Strictly speaking, no "changing" of `recordsize` actually occurs.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old reply, but you CANNOT use `zfs send` + `zfs recv` to change the record size.

I was fooled by reading somewhere that it does change the record size, then I started working on a project where I needed to read a lot about the stream format and found that it always refers to object ids with the record size already present in the stream. Naturally you might think that this is not an issue and it could change it on the receiving end, but because it supports incremental updates it would be impossible to store the FREE commands when it references block IDs + block offsets without storing the original info somewhere in ZFS, which it doesn't.